# RecyclerView.Adapter onBind method not recognizing View items from row xml in android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Creating simple program that takes a list of MAX 4 items, i opted for a **RecyclerView** instead of **ListView** for optimization. I added and binded the **RecyclerView** to my *main.xml* and *MainActivity*, created an ***row.xml*** that defines how each *row* inside the **RecyclerView** will look and created and binded a custom *adapter* that extends **RecyclerView.Adapter** with required methods. My code is posted below ->

```
<!-- This is row.xml -->
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container_4_row"
android:layout_height="@dimen/media_item_height">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover_art"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:contentDescription="@string/play_item"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_container"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        tools:text="The Best Music EVAH1111 FOREVER YOUNG I'M SOME!!!11^H^H"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        tools:text="John Doe, his brothers, his sisters, his pets and his more than amazing band"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> this is Adapter class

```
public class MyRecycleAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView  mAuthor, mTitle;
    private final ImageView aCover;
    private final LinearLayout textContainer;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
            }
        });
        this.textContainer = v.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
        this.mAuthor = v.findViewById(R.id.author);
        this.mTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.aCover = v.findViewById(R.id.cover_art);
    }
    private TextView getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }
    private TextView getAuthor() {
        return mAuthor;
    }
    private ImageView getaCover() {
        return aCover;
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyRecycleAdapter() {
     //mDataset = myDataset;
}


@NonNull
@Override
// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
public MyRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
        @NonNull ViewGroup parent,
        int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: layoutInflator = ");

    // create a new view
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                              final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    viewHolder.getaCover().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    viewHolder.getAuthor().setText("John Doe, his brothers, his sisters");
    viewHolder.getTitle().setText("The Best Music EVAH1111");
}

@Override
// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
public int getItemCount() {
    return 4;
}
}
```

> This is in MainActivity

```
mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    // Setting improve's performance if changes in content don't alter RecyclerView layout size
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // not necessary to achieve goal
    // String[] mew = new String[]{"mew", "two"};

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyRecycleAdapter(mew);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

My Question is when i run the application the RecyclerView.Adapter onBindViewHolder() doesnt recognize the child views inside the parent view holder (which references the ***row.xml***)....i Dont know why it doesnt because earlier it had no problem when i ran it with out inserting any literals or assigning a null to my imageview, it built correctly and now it randomly tweaks. What i tried was, invalidating/clearing cache and restarting AS(did not rectify the issues), i also tried creating a new dummy project and copy and pasting my code, ran it without any issues but I have issues in my main project that has alot of files/helper classes, etc, etc...

> Below is the Error Log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.android.mediasession.ui.auxillary.MyRecycleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyRecycleAdapter.java:67)
                  at com.example.android.mediasession.ui.auxillary.MyRecycleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyRecycleAdapter.java:15)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21103)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1210)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1550)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21103)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21103)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21103)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6462)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:858)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21103)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2573)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1632)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1512)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7094)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6836)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Application terminated.

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: @AndrewMyers the code is posted, i am still working in the issue, I know that its suppose to work, since my POC worked when i created and eventually will delete the dummy project/application, but for the life of me wont work on my original project....is this a type of bug within AS ? does this normally happen? or has this happened to either of you?

Comment: `doesnt recognize the child views inside the parent view holder` what error do you see?

Comment: @Sagar I've posted the Error log, but keep in mind that, no issues arose _when i created a new application and copied/pasted the code/files that were needed_ to view a RecyclerVIew list containing  4 rows, made up of the same imageview and 2 textviews

Comment: Do you have multiple `res/layout*/` folders, where you've possibly created `row` in one without those `View`s?

Comment: @MikeM. yes, i have the _row.xml _layout in the default folder and the v-21 folder, can that affect it? i do have the default _row.xml_ layout child views assigned different ((Id's** than the  'v21'

Comment: Are they both exactly as you've posted above; i.e., with all the `View`s with the exact same IDs? Also, do you necessarily need a different version for v21+?

Comment: Yes, they need to have the exact same IDs. Notice that your code isn't looking for different IDs based on the version.

Comment: @MikeM. Holy F*** Batman!!??, I've update the v21 to match my default folder and now it works! I am not sure if i need a different version for v21+, i thinked it was an accidental folder v21 creation because at the moment i dont know what purpose it serves,....will post the answer and now, is there a way to upvote your comment?

Comment: You would want to have a v21 layout if you want to use things on Android versions 21+ that weren't introduced until v21 (Lollipop); e.g., `ColorStateList`s for `tint`s, Material design-specific attributes, etc. I can't be sure if you do need that separate layout, but it's possible that your IDE auto-generated it for you, just as part of the project template you chose. Anyhoo, there's no need to upvote my comment. Doesn't do much, anyway. :-) Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As @Mike M. pointed out in the comments,

> Do you have multiple res/layout*/ folders, where you've possibly created row in one without those Views? If yes, are they both exactly as you've posted above; i.e., with all the Views with the exact same IDs? Also, do you necessarily need a different version for v21+?

I had two different folders containing the same layout, the default layout folder and v21 folder, however my view Id's and some parent LayoutViews were mismatched, after I updated them to reflect an exact copy in both folders, my application ran like a charm-ander

Answer (score 1):

you're passing two values

```
String[] mew = new String[]{"mew", "two"};
```

and trying to generate 4 row this may produce indexOutOfBounds Exception

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 4;//use your mDataset's size.
}
```

Comment: i specifically placed 4 as the item count in getItemCount() method. i also inserted dummy texts inside the author and title textviews within the onBindViewHolder()

Answer (score 1):

Inside your onBindViewHolder there is a minor mistake,

Update following code, i corrected it.

```
viewHolder.aCover.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
viewHolder.mAuthor.setText("John Doe, his brothers, his sisters"); viewHolder.mTitle.setText("The Best Music EVAH1111");
```

You were referring to wrong view. That was causing error.

Update and let me know if issue gets resolved.

Comment: no that wasnt it, i actually had two different layout folders with mismatching view id's @mikeM pointed it out in the comments above.